# Using strict types in linq grouping query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm querying a collection using linq and grouping my data by `datetime` property using the following code:

```
var querty = from post in ds.Appointments
             group post by new  
             { 
                 Year = post.DateOfVisit.Year, 
                 Month = post.DateOfVisit.Month
             };
```

Everything is good, when use an anonymous type. But If I define my own class

```
class YearMonth
{
    public int Year;
    public string Month;

    public YearMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}",Year,Month);
    }
}
```

and modify my query accordingly

```
var querty = from post in ds.Appointments
             group post by new YearMonth(post.DateOfVisit.Year, 
                                         post.DateOfVisit.Month);
```

then grouping is not working and I'm getting a plain list of the objects. Why?

Comment: Your YearMonth class must implement Equals and GetHashCode.

Comment: @schglurps You should post it as answer!

Comment: @Ask Anonymous types have equality code generated for them, your type doesn't and will default to reference equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As schglurps already said, you have to override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`, since the `GroupBy` method (and others) rely on these.

---

The `GroupBy` method creates the final groups based on the hash code (and equality) of the objects it groups on.

So for each item in your sequence, it checks if there's already a group with the same hash code, then checks if the item is equal to the key of the group. If there's no matching group, it creates a new one.

In your case, since you don't override `GetHashCode`, each instance of `YearMonth` will have a different hash code (collisions aside), so each item will result in a new group being created.

Just have a look at the relevant [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs#57b0aa9f1c572776).

---

Here's an example implementation:

```
public class YearMonth : IEquatable<YearMonth>
{
    public readonly int Year;
    public readonly int Month;

    public YearMonth(int year, int month)
    {
        Year = year;
        Month = month;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", Year, Month);
    }

    public bool Equals(YearMonth other)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, other)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        return Month == other.Month && Year == other.Year;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((YearMonth)obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Month * 397) ^ Year;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(YearMonth left, YearMonth right)
    {
        return Equals(left, right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(YearMonth left, YearMonth right)
    {
        return !Equals(left, right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give some more details how grouping is using these methods and why do I need to have implementation?